# Add and remove classes for multiple elements (JQuery & JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to get a suitable answer to edit the code in my previous question.

Link to previous question:
[Add and remove classes for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328546/add-and-remove-classes-for-multiple-elements/76328793#76328793)

Now I have developed the previous code and added content to it that when the icon is clicked, its content will be shown or hidden.

The problem with this code is that by clicking on any of the available icons, the contents of all of them will appear or hide.

But that's not what I want. I want to display the corresponding content by clicking on each icon, and by clicking on another icon, all the content will be hidden and only the content related to the icon that was clicked will be displayed.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.icon_product', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("change_icon-product");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.icon_product').removeClass("change_icon-product");

    $(this).find(".txt-content").toggleClass("Toggle_txt-content");
 });
```

```css
.icon_product {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.icon-line1_product,
.icon-line2_product {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #f00;
    margin: 6px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.icon-line2_product {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
}

.change_icon-product .icon-line1_product {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
}

.change_icon-product .icon-line2_product {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
}


/* 
*
*
*
 */

.txt-content {
    display: none;
}

.Toggle_txt-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

        <div class="main-content_product">
            <div class="icon_product">
                <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                <div class="txt-content">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                        harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content_product">
            <div class="icon_product">
                <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                <div class="txt-content">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                        harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content_product">
            <div class="icon_product">
                <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                <div class="txt-content">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                        harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: You need to select only the relevant `.txt-content` element, instead of _all_ of them, as you are doing now. `$(".txt-content")` -> `$(this).find(".txt-content")`

Comment: Hi, change `$(".txt-content")` this to `$(this).find(".txt-content").`

Comment: Hello. I applied this change but still the previous content is not hidden. I edited my question with your code.

Comment: I want the contents of the icon to appear or hide as the appearance of the icon changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to remove other contents too, if another one is open for that you only had to add one line of code :

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.txt-content').removeClass("Toggle_txt-content");
```

The above line removes or hides other contents once the another one opens.

Here is the demo :

```js
$('body').on('click', '.icon_product', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("change_icon-product");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.icon_product').removeClass("change_icon-product");
    $(this).find(".txt-content").toggleClass("Toggle_txt-content");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.txt-content').removeClass("Toggle_txt-content");
 });
```

```css
body {
  background: transparent; /* Make it white if you need */
  color: #fcbe24;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.icon_product {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.icon-line1_product,
.icon-line2_product {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #f00;
    margin: 6px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.icon-line2_product {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 0px);
}

.change_icon-product .icon-line1_product {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
}

.change_icon-product .icon-line2_product {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 0px);
}


/* 
*
*
*
 */

.txt-content {
    display: none;
}

.Toggle_txt-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

            <div class="main-content_product">
                <div class="icon_product">
                    <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                    <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                    <div class="txt-content">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                            harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-content_product">
                <div class="icon_product">
                    <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                    <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                    <div class="txt-content">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                            harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-content_product">
                <div class="icon_product">
                    <div class="icon-line1_product test"></div>
                    <div class="icon-line2_product test"></div>

                    <div class="txt-content">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit necessitatibus nobis
                            harum voluptatum fuga, nam tempore exercitationem dolore placeat.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

    </section>
```